# Counting Organizations by using Python and Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

This application will read the mailbox data (mbox.txt) count up the number email messages per organization (i.e. domain name of the email address) using a database with the following schema to maintain the counts.

```
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)
```

When you have run the program on mbox.txt upload the resulting database file above for grading.
If you run the program multiple times in testing or with different files, make sure to empty out the data before each run.

You can use this code as a starting point for your application: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/emaildb.py. The data file for this application is the same as in previous assignments: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox.txt.

First time to learn Sqlite. I am very confused about this assignment although it seems to be easy. I don't know how can I connect Python codes to Sqlite. It seems that they don't need the code as assignment. All the need is database file. How should I solve this problem. Don't know how to start it. Much appreciated it!

Comment: What is your question? The first three lines of the code create a database file and connect to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The starting code you've been given is a really good template for what you want to do. The difference is that - in that example - you're counting occurences of email address, and in this problem you're counting domains.

First thing to do is think about how to get domain names from email addresses. Building from the code given (which sets email = pieces[1]):

```
domain = email.split('@')[1]
```

This will break the email on the @ character, and return the second item (the part after the '@'), which is the domain - the thing you want to count.

After this, go through the SQL statements in the code and replace 'email' with 'domain', so that you're counting the right thing.

One last thing - the template code checks 'mbox-short.txt' - you'll need to edit that as well for the file you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
   import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'mbox.txt'
fh = open(fname)
list_1 =[]
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    dom = email.find('@')
    org = email[dom+1:len(email)]

    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count)
                VALUES (?, 1)''', (org,))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE org = ?',
                    (org,))
conn.commit()
# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still new here, but I want to thank Stidgeon for pointing me in the right direction. I suspect other Using Databases with Python students will end up here too.

There are two things you need to do with the source code.

1. domain = email.split('@')[1] http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/emaildb.py
2. Change from email TEXT to org TEXT when the database is generated.

That should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    org = pieces[1].split('@')
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org[1],))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count)
                VALUES (?, 1)''', (org[1],))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE org = ?',
                    (org[1],))
conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
print('-----------------done----------------')
```